# Is it possible to use React.js on the client side only with my traditional stack

Tags: jquery, reactjs

I've got a web application. It's got a very traditional technology stack. The server side is Apache Struts, the database is db2 and on the client side I am using JQuery. The application is deployed over websphere.

Recently I have started to use JQuery heavily on a number of pages and I have slowly started to see the JQuery code behind certain pages turn into spaghetti code.

I am looking to use some of the newer javascript frameworks to give the client side JQuery more structure. Unfortunately I am tied to the server side technologies I am using.

I have been reading lately about React.js but I am a bit confused about whether this technology is meant to be server side or client side.

Can I keep my server side technologies and use React.js to give my client side JQuery code more structure?

Also I believe there is some built in capability in React.js to build a mobile application. Could I make that work if I use my current server side technologies and add React.js to only my client side (if that's possible).

thanks

Comment: React is a library for building UI. While jQuery is an abstraction layer for doing DOM manipulations. If you want to introduce MVC in your client code you should take a look at AngularJS or simulare.

Comment: So applying that comment to my own application, my application builds the UI on the server side and is maniupulated on the client side using jquery. Is that correct? Hence React.js does not suit my setup and I should look at Angular?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this works fine--React simply renders components, you can use it with any server rendering technology you want to. You can also utilize it along many other client-side data libraries to build more complex things.

However, one thing React is *not* quite as good at is [progressive enhancement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement), which traditionally jQuery has been pretty good at. React expects to be able to completely control a piece of the DOM, so rendering something and then "enhancing" it with React isn't as easily done.

Comment: hmm that interesting. A very different answer to the comment from @dev-null . So what I think you saying in your statement is that I could make it work with my current technology stack but I would have to move all the server side html rendering to the client side?

Comment: @Richie Kinda. You could certainly render most of your HTML on the server, and then use React to build rich UI components in various places on the page. But a lot of people render the HTML 100% on the server, and then use jQuery to bind handlers to the *existing* HTML to "enhance" it, e.g. making some links/forms use Ajax. React doesn't work quite like that.

Comment: The last bit of your previous comment is exactly how I'm usin jquery. So therefore it sounds like React doesn't really suit me. Thanks for the advice you have given me.